# d3 arc transition error when toggling sweep-flag

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to implement a transition of an arc to flip its direction as well as its degree of curvature with the following code:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200);
var sweepFlag0 = 0,
    sweepFlag1 = 1;
var curve1 = 'M30,30A10,10 0 0 ' + sweepFlag0 + ' 100,100';
var curve2 = 'M30,30A100,100 0 0 ' + sweepFlag0 + ' 100,100'; // error if use sweepFlag1

svg.append('path')
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('d', curve1)
  .transition().duration(1000)
  .attr('d', curve2);
</script>
```

It works when curve1 and curve2 share the same sweep-flag value (sweepFlag0 or sweepFlag1). However in order to flip the direction of curvature, errors are produced when the two sweep-flag values differ. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to transition between an arc sweep value of [`1` and `0` (clockwise or counter-clockwise)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d#arcto) but that isn't possible because the value is binary (ie discrete and not continuous). You should try using [`curveto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d#curveto) instead of `arcto` because `curveto`s use [Bezier curves](https://developer.mozilla.org/User:Jt//Sandbox/Curves_in_Paths) which are much more powerful than the elliptical curves in arcs.

Something like this:

```
var curve1 = 'M0,0 C100,0 100,0 100,100'
var curve2 = 'M0,0 C20,80 20,80 100,100'

svg.append('path')
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('d', curve1)
  .transition().duration(1000)
  .attr('d', curve2)
```

Check out these resources too:

- https://css-tricks.com/svg-path-syntax-illustrated-guide/

EDIT for keeping arcs:

```
var sweepFlag0 = 0,
    sweepFlag1 = 1;

var curve1 = 'M30,30A10,10 0 0 ' + sweepFlag0 + ' 100,100';
var curve2 = 'M30,30A8000,8000 0 0 ' + sweepFlag0 + ' 100,100';
var curve3 = 'M30,30A8000,8000 0 0 ' + sweepFlag1 + ' 100,100';
var curve4 = 'M30,30A100,100 0 0 ' + sweepFlag1 + ' 100,100';

svg.append('path')
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('d', curve1)
  .transition().duration(500)
  .attr('d', curve2)
  .transition().duration(0)
  .attr('d', curve3)
  .transition().duration(500)
  .attr('d', curve4)
```

This method is a little hacky but it's the best I can think of as there's no actual transition that is theoretically possible between two ellipses of opposite curvature. What this method is doing is increasing the radius to such a large value that the line *appears* straight. Now that it appears straight, you can sneak in a flip in the curvature without the user noticing, after which you'll be able to further transition the curvature however you'd like. Try playing around with passing in an [ease function](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/1ea51d03775b9650e8dfd03474e202fe) to get the transition to appear a little smoother

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works for changing the direction of an non-circular arc. But I need circular arcs. I wonder if there is a way to make circular arcs using Bezier or other alternatives.

Comment: Unfortunately, getting a Bezier curve to emulate circularity requires some impractically complex approximations. Check out my edit if you really must use arcs

Comment: That's a smart solution! Thanks a lot.